# Website is scrolling sideways + missing bottom border

Tags: css

I have a website called http://www.willtakesurveysforfood.com/. On that website I have two issues:

- The navigation bar is making my website scroll sideways. The width is at 100% so I'm not sure what's wrong.
- The bottom border of the .POST Div is missing.

If I can get any help that'd be great. Thanks!

Comment: the navigation should be inside wrapper i think, or give it the same width, Your .post div has inline style="border-bottom:none;" :-)

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it

Comment: Thank you very much. I had no idea why that there, haha.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the padding from your UL. Since you have given your UL a width of 100 % the padding will be added on top of that, unless you use a box model.

Gatekeeper answered your other question in a comment.